# Query Inner Duplicates Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

i have a query to select multiple values in 4 Tables however i only need the matches of one inner join on two Tables This is my Query:

```
SELECT  [dbo].[CHEQUES].Fecha, 
        [dbo].[TURNOS].Descripcion,
        [dbo].[CAPMO].Clave_PDV, 
        [dbo].[CAPMO].Pla AS Platillo_Id, 
        [dbo].[CAPMO].Descripcion, 
        [dbo].[CAPMO].Precio_Neto AS PrecioPlatillo, 
        [dbo].[CAPMO].Can AS CantidadPlatillo

        FROM         [dbo].[CAPMO] 
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[CHEQUES] ON [dbo].[CAPMO].Clave_PDV = [dbo].[CHEQUES].Cla_PDV AND [dbo].[CAPMO].Che = [dbo].[CHEQUES].Che 
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[PLATILLOS] ON [dbo].[CAPMO].Pla = [dbo].[PLATILLOS].Pla 
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[TURNOS] ON [dbo].[CHEQUES].Tur = [dbo].[TURNOS].Tur
```

This is my

```
**[dbo].[CHEQUES]:
|Cla_Pdv    |    Che    |    Fecha    |    Tur    |**
---------------------------------------------------       
|   FUEM    |    4423   |2016-01-01   |     2     |
--------------------------------------------------- 

**[dbo].[TURNO]:
|Clave_Pdv    |    Tur    |    Descripcion    |**
-----------------------------------------------     
|   FUEM      |     1     |      DESAYUNOS    |
-----------------------------------------------
|   FUEM      |     2     |      COMIDAS      |
-----------------------------------------------
|   FUEM      |     3     |      CENAS        |
-----------------------------------------------

**[dbo].[CAPMO]:
|Clave_Pdv    |    Che    |    Com    |    Pla    |    Descripcion    |    Precio_Neto    |    Can    |**
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
|   FUEM      |     4423  |      1    |    184    |    POZ            |    85             |    1    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   FUEM      |     4423  |      2    |    184    |    POZ            |    85             |    1    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   FUEM      |     4423  |      3    |    184    |    POZ            |    84             |    1    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**[dbo].[Platillos]:
|    Pla    |    Des    |    Pre   |**
------------------------------------
|   184    |     4423  |      85   |
------------------------------------
|   244    |     4423  |      84   |
------------------------------------
```

My actual output give me alot of data and it shoul only give me 3 rows of data
This is my output Data:

```
|  2016-01-01   |  COMIDAS  |  4423 |  FUEM |  184  |  POZ    |  85 |  1  |
|  2016-01-01   |  COMIDAS  |  4423 |  FUEM |  184  |  POZ    |  85 |  1  |
|  2016-01-01   |  COMIDAS  |  4423 |  FUEM |  184  |  POZ    |  85 |  1  |
|  2016-01-01   |  COMIDAS  |  4423 |  FUEM |  184  |  POZ    |  85 |  1  |
|  2016-01-01   |  COMIDAS  |  4423 |  FUEM |  184  |  POZ    |  85 |  1  |
|  2016-01-01   |  COMIDAS  |  4423 |  FUEM |  184  |  POZ    |  85 |  1  |
|  2016-01-01   |  COMIDAS  |  4423 |  FUEM |  184  |  POZ    |  85 |  1  |
|  2016-01-01   |  COMIDAS  |  4423 |  FUEM |  184  |  POZ    |  85 |  1  |
|  2016-01-01   |  COMIDAS  |  4423 |  FUEM |  244  |  AGUA   |  84 |  1  |
|  2016-01-01   |  COMIDAS  |  4423 |  FUEM |  244  |  AGUA   |  84 |  1  |
|  2016-01-01   |  COMIDAS  |  4423 |  FUEM |  244  |  AGUA   |  84 |  1  |
|  2016-01-01   |  COMIDAS  |  4423 |  FUEM |  244  |  AGUA   |  84 |  1  |
```

But i need my Output to be:

```
| 2016-01-01 |  COMIDAS |  4423 |  FUEM |  184 | POZ |  85 |    2|
| 2016-01-01 |  COMIDAS |  4423 |  FUEM |  184 | POZ |  84 |    1|
```

Since there are 3 lines on  my [dbo].CAPMO but 1 of them has the same 'Pla' value so i must increment the 'Can' item for the same table '[dbo].[CAPMO]' thats why i need my output like this but in my actual output it seems its multiplying the real value in four columns

What am i doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I updated my query to get just exactly the output i want but i had to cut one table out of my query i updated my query to this:

```
SELECT [dbo].[CHEQUES].Fecha,                         
    [dbo].[CHEQUES].Che,
    [dbo].[CAPMO].Clave_PDV, 
    [dbo].[CAPMO].Pla AS Platillo_Id, 
    [dbo].[CAPMO].Descripcion, 
    [dbo].[CAPMO].Precio_Neto AS PrecioPlatillo, 
    sum( [dbo].[CAPMO].Can) AS CantidadPlatillo

    FROM   [dbo].[CAPMO] 
    Left JOIN [dbo].[Cheques] on [dbo].[Capmo].Che = [dbo].[Cheques].Che

    group by  [dbo].[CHEQUES].Fecha,[dbo].[CHEQUES].Che, [dbo].[CAPMO].Clave_PDV,[dbo].[CAPMO].Pla,[dbo].[CAPMO].Descripcion,[dbo].[2016_01_01_CAPMO].Precio_Neto
```

This new query makes my output:

```
| 2016-01-01 |  4423    |  FUEM |  184 | POZ |  85 |    2|
| 2016-01-01 |  4423    |  FUEM |  184 | POZ |  84 |    1|
```

It gives me the data i need and increases the Quantity correctly but i stil need 1 column that matches the [dbo].[TURNOS], like in this JOIN:

```
JOIN [dbo].[2016_01_01_TURNOS] ON [dbo].[2016_01_01_CHEQUES].Tur = [dbo].[2016_01_01_TURNOS].Tur
```

But adding a new join to my query multiply my results and i only need the same output i have but with the column of the data in [dbo].[Turnos], how can i do this?

Comment: as you know inner join produces a Cartesian product depending on the tables (rows) you are joining, that's why you will see more records than expected, what about using a derived tables to get the result you want and then join as necessary, or remove unnecessary tables within the query just use the ones you need to get the output.

Comment: im using the only one i need the output i need data from 4 diferent tables but the specific inner join that matter should be between Cheques and CApmo on the field how should i change my query?

Comment: Mysql and ms sql are two different products. Which one do you use?

Comment: There's always the option of `SELECT DISTINCT ...`

Comment: even with distinc adding the second join multiply the results so no changes with distinc i only need 2 row of results not 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there should not be duplicated information if you are doing the JOIN in this way :

```
JOIN [dbo].[2016_01_01_TURNOS] ON [dbo].[2016_01_01_CHEQUES].Tur = [dbo].[2016_01_01_TURNOS].Tur
```

but I think we can do something this way :

```
SELECT [dbo].[CHEQUES].Fecha,                         
[dbo].[CHEQUES].Che,
[dbo].[CAPMO].Clave_PDV, 
[dbo].[CAPMO].Pla AS Platillo_Id, 
[dbo].[CAPMO].Descripcion, 
[dbo].[CAPMO].Precio_Neto AS PrecioPlatillo, 
sum( [dbo].[CAPMO].Can) AS CantidadPlatillo,
Dev.Descripcion 
FROM   [dbo].[CHEQUES]   
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Cq.Che, t.Descripcion FROM [dbo].[TURNO] t INNER JOIN [dbo].[CHEQUES] Cq ON Cq.Tur = t.tUR 
) AS Dev ON Dev.Che = Cheques.Che 
Left JOIN [dbo].[CAPMO] on [dbo].[Capmo].Che = [dbo].[Cheques].Che

group by  [dbo].[CHEQUES].Fecha,[dbo].[CHEQUES].Che, [dbo].[CAPMO].Clave_PDV,[dbo].[CAPMO].Pla,[dbo].[CAPMO].Descripcion,[dbo].[2016_01_01_CAPMO].Precio_Neto,Dev.Descripcion
```

let me know if that works otherwise we can figure it out something.

Comment: El query me envia un error que dice, La columna 'Dev.Descripcion' de la lista de seleccion no es valida, porque no esta contenida en una funcion de agregado ni en la clausula group by

Comment: please try again, missing the last part for the aggregate function, which was simple to add